# How does Windows XP determine what application to start when a CD ROM is loaded?

Tags: windows-xp, compact-disc, file-association, autorun

How does Windows XP determine what application to start when a CD ROM movie is loaded?

In other words, if you put a CD-ROM movie in the computers CD ROM player then close the door, an application starts to play the move. How does XP know what application to start?

Answer (score 0):

It is in your system defaults.  You can change this setting, here is info on how: [Windows XP autoplay](http://www.winbookcorp.com/_technote/WBTA20000846.htm).  You can change this setting for more then your CD-Rom.  Things like default text editor.

Comment: This is not right. The settings for my CD-ROM drives are all "Select an Action Each Time", but when I put a CD in, an application is automatically starting.

Comment: What application is starting?  Have you tried telling windows to start a different application instead.  Then maybe setting it back to "select an action each time".